# Combining multiple queries

Tags: sql

I want a table with all customers and their last charge transaction date *and* their last invoice date. I have the first two, but don't know how to add the last invoice date to the table. Here's what I have so far:

```
WITH

--Last customer transaction 
cust_trans AS (
        SELECT customer_id, created
        FROM charges a
        WHERE created = (
           SELECT MAX(created) AS last_trans
           FROM charges b
           WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id)),

--All customers
all_cust AS (
        SELECT customers.id AS customer, customers.email, CAST(customers.created AS DATE) AS join_date, ((1.0 * customers.account_balance)/100) AS balance
    FROM customers),
    
--Last customer invoice    
cust_inv AS (
        SELECT customer_id, date
        FROM invoices a
        WHERE date = (
       SELECT MAX(date) AS last_inv
           FROM invoices b
           WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id))
        
SELECT * FROM cust_trans
RIGHT JOIN all_cust ON all_cust.customer = cust_trans.customer_id
ORDER BY join_date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get what you need.  Notice each individual subquery is left-joined to the customer table, so you always START with the customer, and IF there is a corresponding record in each subquery for max charge date or max invoice date, it will be pulled in.  Now, you may want to apply a `COALESCE()` for the max dates to prevent showing nulls, such as

```
COALESCE(maxCharges.LastChargeDate, '') AS LastChargeDate
```

but your call.

```
SELECT
    c.id AS customer, 
    c.email, 
    CAST(c.created AS DATE) AS join_date, 
    ((1.0 * c.account_balance) / 100) AS balance,
    maxCharges.LastChargeDate,
    maxInvoices.LastInvoiceDate
FROM
    customers c
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         customer_id,
         MAX(created) LastChargeDate
     FROM
         charges
     GROUP BY
         customer_id) maxCharges ON c.id = maxCharges.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         customer_id,
         MAX(date) LastInvoiceDate
     FROM
         invoices
     GROUP BY
         customer_id) maxInvoices ON c.id = maxInvoices.customer_id
ORDER BY
    c.created
```

Comment: For this and future.  Upchecks on answers help indicate what helped you in learning, and for YOUR questions, clicking the CheckMark next to an answer that solves your problems helps others with similar issues to know what worked for you.